# Netbeans (6.9.1) installation error

Tags: netbeans

While installing netbeans-6.9.1 I got following error:

```
./netbeans-6.9.1-ml-linux.sh: 1897: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ";;")
```

What may be the reason? I have downloaded the installer from netbeans.org.

Comment: Any reason why you don't wantto install netbeans from software center - sudo apt-get install netbeans? The version there is also 6.9

Comment: i want to install 6.9.1 so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `sh ./netbeans-6.9.1-ml-linux.sh`  .

Or anyway, that worked for me:

```
$ sh netbeans-6.9.1-ml-linux.sh 
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
```

If that's not working, we may need to look at whether you have any missing dependencies....

In the installer I just downloaded, line 1897 is:

```
            printf "Executando o assistente do instalador...\n"
```

Not a "`(`" in sight on mine.

Here's the md5sum of the file I have:

```
$ md5sum  netbeans-6.9.1-ml-linux.sh 
9b00ecdc6e7a80dec5b882343d0ed6db  netbeans-6.9.1-ml-linux.sh
```

And here's my system (Ubuntu 10.10 with `uname -a`) :

```
Linux mercator 2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 17:40:44 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: i found that there the file was not donwloaded properly. its md5 sum doesnt match. i downloaded net installer and installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the very first line of the script: does it try to run with /bin/sh? If so, change that first line to cause the script to run with BASH instead:

```
#!env bash
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Because /bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/dash, which might be the cause. Or you could invoke the script with bash directly:

```
bash $script
```

Or you could install from repository:

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Comment: It does have ` #!/bin/sh ` -- what's the technical reason for running it under bash, though?

Comment: It's not hard to find discussions on that! Maybe a good starting point: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh.

Comment: In short, /bin/sh on Ubuntu is a symbolic link to /bin/dash. Historically on Linux, /bin/sh has often been a symbolic link to /bin/bash. The way people should write their scripts for "any *nix" has changed, but few script writers have adopted those changes.